# Can I Search a class using this method in javascript

Tags: javascript

I wanted to find a class based on id passed by onclick event on saveDetails, what would be the best approach in doing this?

on my HTML

```
                    <form id="userDetails" >

                    <select class="formdetails" name="status">
                      <option value="' . $status . '">' . $status . '</option>
                      <option value="' . $status1 . '">' . $status1 . '</option>
                    </select>

                    </form>

<td><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" onclick="editUser(\'' . $row["id"] . '\')"></a><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-saved" onclick="saveDetails(\'' . $row["id"] . '\')"></a></td>

 function saveDetails(id){
var userData = '';
formclass = '.formdetails'+id;
userData = $("#userDetails").find('????').serialize()+'&action_type=details&id='+id;
}
```

inserting the variable formclass inside the parethesis doesn't seem to work.. T_T

Comment: Can you post your onclick code, or where you are calling `saveDetails`

Comment: Can you show an example of your data? It's not very clear what you want to achieve and whether you are looking for a `class` or an `id`

Comment: kind of working with rows on table, wanted to updated each row with a click event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be suffixing the row ID on to the class name of `formdetails` in your JS but your HTML code shows only a `formdetails` class, not one which has something after it.

If this is inside a loop, you will want to add the ID to the `formdetails` class name of the `select`

```
<select class="formdetails' . $row["id"] . '" name="status">
```

Given that the ID would be 1, your class would look like `formdetails1`, which could then be accessed from your Javascript as intended.

Comment: what do I do next with .find('dynamicclassnames')? T_T

Comment: You would keep it the same as you have `'.formdetails'+id;` since the HTML now has that class